# How to reverse the direction of operation of the motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, buck

For Synchronous buck, half bridge converter, how to reverse the direction of operation of the motor? That would be great if you could explain me with the circuit diagram.

Comment: Do you have a half-bridge converter IC? Or are you looking for the  schematics for one?

Comment: A synchronous buck isn't by itself a motor driver.  What type of motor are you driving and how are you driving it?  Do you have a DC brush motor powered by a buck?  In that case you can reverse the leads to reverse the direction of rotation.  If you need to do it on the fly an H-bridge is the usual solution.  You'll have to be more clear with your question.

Comment: sorry if my question isn't clear. My question is how to draw the circuit diagram of Synchronous buck, half bridge converter,if I have the forklift battery pack is 72V nominal with max voltage under charge of 90 V. The motor is DC series wond motor with max ratings of 100 V and 300 A. The motor has high inductance. and how to reverse the direction of operation of motor?

Comment: Cannot be answered without knowing what kind of motor. Circuitry to reverse a permanent magnet DC motor will leave a field-wound motor running in the same direction! For a series wound motor, reverse either the field or armature connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple,
For example: In case of three phase induction motor 
1. You can interchange or reverse any of the two input phases of voltage supply.